# Global Filewatcher in C#

Tags: c#, windows, filesystems

I want to detect whether the windows user starts or uses or even interacts with a file, cancel the event and check the file using my C# program. When my program said O.K. the interacts can continue.

Is that possible? I've heared of the Filewatcher but I don't want to watch for a specific file, I want to watch for every file.

Comment: Watching every file will likely lead to serious performance consequences. I would advise against it.

Comment: I don't want to watch every file, I want an event that triggers when you interact with a file. The interaction must be stopable and continueable

Comment: Look into Windows Explorer hooks. Seems like I recall something like this from a few years back. Anti-Virus programs do it, so you should be able to as well.

Comment: There are many Windows Explorer hooks. Can you send me a link?